# Is there a better way to create this screw-like structure?

Tags: mesh, screw-modifier

So, as a blender newbie, I created this shape (and must create more that are similar) by basically drawing it using vertices and edges. It shows a very specific spiral structure that I need.

[image: render of the structure]

While I am generally happy with the result, I think it would be made better by "smoothing out" the unnecessary faces - meaning those that exist, but are not highlighted in the render shown above. Is there a way to make something like this with the screw modifier?

[image: screenshot of the structure]

Comment: IMO the screw mod can only get you partway there, it's really more designed  for perfect spiral  iterations, it doesn't really work with stuff like this that is asymmetrical. But you could use it to generate the basic form and then just apply it and shift the verts where they need to go for the final step. Try it and see if it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There's also an array modifier, geometry nodes and python scripting to consider. For an object that simple it's best to just model it by hand. If you need more "levels", then automating it starts to be a reasonable option. If you have more different screws to generate, then you would need to show at least a few so we can figure out a common denominator.

Comment: Thank you both for commenting. Jakemoyo's suggestion of applying the screw modifier (I didn't even know you could apply modifiers before this) and then changing verts ended up producing a very good result!